# What is a name of System.runAs construction

Tags: apex, runas

As I know Apex is a combination of Java and C# languages (maybe this list should contain more languages).

Speaking about `System.runAs`, documentation says that it is a [method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_tools_runas.htm). It looks like it is a static method of `System` class. But how can then we send written code in block of this method?

```
System.runAs(u){
    //any lines of code are here
}
```

Normally we can't pass code lines to method, so it doesn't look like method. So we can't call `System.runAs` as "method".
I didn't find something relevant in Java. Is it an [anonymous method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2755445/how-can-i-write-an-anonymous-function-in-java), implementation of some interface with anonymous class? Is it something specific only for Apex ?

What is a name of construction `System.runAs(u){}` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT: In C# they're just called "statements". See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement

Comment: thanks for answer, but I know for what is it using. My question is  about what is a proper name of `System.runAs(u) {}` construction.

Comment: Ah sorry. I missunderstood - thought you asked how to use it. In C# they're just called statements (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement)

Comment: can you update your answer with it?

Comment: Sure. I've added it above the "runAs" explanation

Comment: They're called statements in Python too. This functionality is similar to how the `with` keyword works.